# Teradata SQL and not vs and

Tags: sql, teradata

I have a table I am trying to split.

The original table is 1,390k rows, I have three conditions A, B and C which  I would like to use to split the table up.

This query returns 60k rows

```
sel stuff
from table
where  ( A and C)
and (B and C)
```

This query returns 1,060k rows:

```
sel stuff
from table
where  not ( A and C)
and not (B and C)
```

My question is why is the second query returning 1,060k rows, and not 1,330k as I would expect?

Comment: What if `where  not ( ( A and C) and (B and C)) `

Comment: Any null values?

Comment: @JaydipJ That logic doesn't return anything.

Comment: @jarlh No there are no nulls in the data.

Comment: `create table tb (a boolean, b boolean, c boolean)` Add data (all 8 combinations). Try your queries!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The opposite of `(A & C) & (B & C)` is not `!(A & C) & !(B & C)` but `!((A & C) & (B & C))`.

As no sample data is shared, i am Assuming that your table has sample data as below.

```
a   b   c
---------
0   0   0
1   0   0
0   1   0
0   0   1
1   1   0
0   1   1
1   0   1
1   1   1
```

You origional query is as below

```
select * from t1
where ( A=1 and C=1)
and (B=1 and C=1);
```

**Result 1:**

```
a   b   c
---------
1   1   1
```

The query you proposed to generate opposite result of the above query is as below which will never generate your desired result.

```
select * from t1
where not(A=1 and C=1)
and not(B=1 and C=1);
```

**Result 2:**

```
a   b   c
---------
0   0   0
1   0   0
0   1   0
0   0   1
1   1   0
```

Any of the below query will generate the result opposite to your original query.

```
select * from t1
where not(( A=1 and C=1)
and (B=1 and C=1));

select * from t1
where A<>1 or B<>1 or C<>1;
```

**Result 3:**

```
a   b   c
---------
0   0   0
1   0   0
0   1   0
0   0   1
1   1   0
0   1   1
1   0   1
```

As to be seen from above queries results, `result 1` is the exact opposite of `result 3`. You can check the demo [**here**](http://rextester.com/QGNIN25951)

Comment: Or simply: `where A<>1 or B<>1 or C<>1` :-)

Comment: @dnoeth: Yeah true and as always, intuitive :-)

Answer (score 1):

The opposite of `x and y` is `not x OR not y`.

Comment: not x OR not y produced the same behaviour as my second query in the question

Comment: And there are indeed no nulls? Okay, it would really help to see the actual query and datatypes of columsn involved ... 
and confirm that what you tested was

`not (a and c) or not(b and c)`. 

Plus the logical equivalent of your first query:

`a and c and b`

Answer (score 1):

I see this already has an answer.  However, I thought it is worth mentioning a method that doesn't require you to think too hard about what the logical inverse of the original query is.

If the goal in the second query is just to get everything that is not in the first query, maybe your second query should be something like this:

```
sel stuff --This part gets the new records
from table
Minus --This part is the original query and excludes those records
sel stuff
from table
where  ( A and C)
and (B and C)
```